# get value form and if it is null, leave the field empty for input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi I have automated my field but if the value to be retrieved is null it puts error undefined method for nil: NilClass how I solve this problem in the view with get value

Controller

```
   def show
   

     @ref_entraineur = CarriereDocumentFootballeur.where(id: params[:id])

  end
```

in views

```
<%= f.text_field :num_entraineur , label: "Numéro Entraineur " , value: @ref_entraineur.last.num_entraineur    %>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately your question is not understandable. Can you try to describe what it is you are trying to do from a [user story](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/agile-software-development/what-is-user-story/)? If you're stuggling with english you might want to see if you have someone who could help you to translate your question or rephrase it so that is at least understandable.

Answer (score 0):

As **@ref_entraineur** can be nill, you can't call *last.num_entraineur* directly on it because if @ref_entraineur is nil, it won't respond to those fields/methods. So, to be more safe, you should use "safe navigation operator" (&) in your form/view, like this:

```
value: @ref_entraineur&.last&.num_entraineur
```

This way, if **@ref_entraineur** was nil (record not found), the value of your *f.text_field :num_entraineur* would be nil/empty string and no runtime error would be raised.